# loadConnectedPlayers returning a buffer of 0 players

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm working on an unpublished google play app which I want to integrate with google play services. In the game, I want to be able to display friends (people in your Google+ circles) who also play the game, so you can send eachother gifts and visit eachother. Seems like [loadConnectedPlayers()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/Players.html#loadConnectedPlayers(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20boolean)) is ideal for this. Here's how I'm implementing this:

```
 Games.Players.loadConnectedPlayers(mHelper.getApiClient(), true).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Players.LoadPlayersResult>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onResult(Players.LoadPlayersResult loadPlayersResult)
        {          
            if(loadPlayersResult != null)
            {
                if (loadPlayersResult.getStatus().getStatusCode() == GamesStatusCodes.STATUS_OK)
                {
                    if (loadPlayersResult.getPlayers() != null)
                    {
                        PlayerBuffer playerBuffer = loadPlayersResult.getPlayers();
                        Log.d(TAG, "Number of players returned: "+ playerBuffer.getCount());

                        for (int i =0; i<playerBuffer.getCount(); ++i)
                        {                                
                            // TODO: Stuff with each player
                        }

                        playerBuffer.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

However, I'm getting a buffer of 0 players returned. The status code for the result is STATUS_OK, meaning there weren't any errors. The two test players I am using both have authorized the game, both have eachother in their circles, and have public permissions for the game. I can't see any issues in my code, so I'm wondering if this an issue with the app not being published yet? If so, how does one test social features on an unpublished app? Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Update: I've also tried the google plus API's loadConnected, with the exact same problem. However, using google plus' loadVisible does correctly pull down the test account in my circles. Ultimately this won't be sufficient though as I want users that are in my circles but only those who also use this app.

Comment: any solution on this?

Comment: Not really. Even in our live games we seem to have a lot of trouble getting people to show up on this list even when they have one another in circles and have all the permissions set to public - even in the Google Play app they often don't show up under "following". It may be the test accounts we are using are fouled up somehow, though.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'm assuming the same with test accounts. Could any confirm the behaviour?